# Make an inline script interact with rendered components in Astro

Tags: javascript, html, astrojs

I have a script that is used to toggle dark mode. The script saves the theme preference to the local storage and applies the modifications to the DOM accordingly. The default theme in the HTML is dark. When in the local storage the white theme preference has been saved, the DOM is modified upon rendering with an **annoying flickering**. To fix that, I followed [this](https://axellarsson.com/blog/astrojs-prevent-dark-mode-flicker/) guide, and I tried to execute the theme script before the loading of the page. Here is a sample of my current `Layout.astro`:

```
<head>
  <script is:inline>
    // The configured mode is stored in local storage
    const isDarkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');

    // Set theme to 'dark' if darkMode = 'true'
    const theme = isDarkMode === 'true' ? 'dark' : '';

    // Put dark class on html tag to enable dark mode
    document.querySelector("html").className = theme;
   
    // Change other elements accordingly
    document.querySelectorAll(".my").className = theme;

  </script>
...
</head>
```

Styles are defined in a single .css file. And here is part of `index.astro`

```
<Layout>
  <Navbar navLinks={navLinks} />

  <Hero />

  <Bar />

  <Foo />

  <Contacts />
</Layout>
```

The problem is that my `.my-element` elements are scattered in all the components (i.e., `Navbar`, `Hero`, etc.). Since the inline script is defined in `Layout.astro`, it can't access the `.my-element` elements inside the components. If I remove `is:inline`, it works, but of course I come back to the starting point.

Is there a way to fix? Ideally, I'd need to modify the classes associated to the elements before the stylesheet is applied.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you probably want to change how your icon components work. You can use the same class name set on the html element to change their styling.

I'm not sure what your styles look like currently but if they're something like `.icon.light { ... }` they could become `.light .icon { ... }` (the space in this second one is important!)

Additionally, if you're writing these styles using Astro's scoped CSS, you'll need to explicitly say that the light class comes from outside the icon component by using `:global()` around the class on the html element:

```
---
// Icon.Astro
---
<svg class="icon">...</svg>

<style>
.icon {
  /* dark styles */
}

:global(.light) .icon {
  /* light styles */
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. My .icon elements are actually some elements scattered through components sensible to theme toggling. They are not actual icons or something managed by Icon.Astro. I'll edit my question to avoid misconceptions.

Comment: I think the same approach can apply if I'm understanding correctly: you have some global CSS for `.my-element` and want to apply different CSS for the different themes. You can do that with the CSS class on the html element: `.light .my-element` will style all instances of `.my-element` that are _inside_ an element with the class `.light`.